# android bitmap.getConfig() = null

Tags: bitmap, null, config

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, op);
bmp.getConfig() = null;
```

---

why `bmp.getConfig() = null;`

anybody who knows, please help me!

Comment: According to documentation of getConfig method
If the bitmap's internal config is in one of the public formats, getConfig return that config, otherwise return null.

Comment: is there any solution that can avoid it returns null?

Comment: Check your inputStream. Check whether image can be viewed.

Comment: inputstream does not throw any exception and the image can be viewed in the image browser.so is there exits other possibility?

Comment: Possibility to do what? What are you trying to do? Try to use ARGB_8888 config by default.

Comment: if (bmp.getConfig()==null){Config type = Config.ARGB888;}imgIn = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, type);In this way ,it will  throw memeory is not enough exception.

Comment: Please provide source code when you initialize inputStream, width and height variables. It is hard to see what is going on in your code by pieces of code you provided. Also try load another image.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Bitmaps decoded from GIFs don't have a config. From AOSP's Bitmap source code,

```
public static Bitmap createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height, Matrix m, boolean filter) {

   final Config config = source.getConfig();
        // GIF files generate null configs, assume ARGB_8888
        if (config != null) {
            ...
        }

}
```